# Show ‘tags’ for a post on the frontend when in a list view

Tags: tags

Show ‘tags’ for a post on the frontend when in a list view. When these are toggled on we will show #tag-name next to the categories of the post. See the screenshot provided as reference.[image]

Comment: To add tags to that view you just need to work out which template it's using and edit that. You've tagged this plugin-development: you may be able to do this from a plugin with the right hooks, but I suspect you'll need to edit your theme (or create a child theme and edit that)

Comment: I don't know what you mean "when these are toggled on" though. How / where would you toggle these on? Would you do that on the server side e.g. in a search form, or on the client? I don't see anything like that on your image.